# How to make an "if" based on value retrieved from Query?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert into a table "pass" or "fail", if from the query done there is a single fail instead of 'RProva' I have to put "fail" if the query can't find a single fail instead of 'RProva' I have to insert "pass", the query is working but I can't figure out how to do the if with the results  of a query, maybe I have to use a "for"? Don't know. It is the attempt to make it, the second is the query where I have to insert the result of the possbile "IF"

1.

```
    SqlCommand cmdRD = new SqlCommand("SELECT ResItem AS RD FROM tSE JOIN tL ON tSE.idSE=tL.idL WHERE tL.Selection=1");
    var RD = cmdRD.ExecuteScalar();

    var values = new List<string>();
    using (cmdRD,sqliteCon)
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdRD.ExecuteReader())
         {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                values.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

2.

```
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tSD(NomeItem,ResItemDet,DateStartDet,DateEndDet) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES (@NI,@RProva,@DATESE,@DATEED)");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESE", DATESE);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", DATEED);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NI", NI);


    using (cmd1,sqliteCon)
    {
          foreach (var value in values)
          {
             if (value.Equals(pass))
             {
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", value);
             }
             else
             {
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", fail);
             }
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
    }

    int generatedId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();


    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tSE SET FK_TSD_id = @tsdId FROM tL JOIN tSE ON tL.idL = tSE.idSE WHERE tL.Selection=1 ", sqliteCon);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsdId", generatedId);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Dato Aggiunto");

  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
```

1.1

```
    SqlCommand cmdRD = new SqlCommand("SELECT ResItem AS RD FROM tSE JOIN tL ON tSE.idSE=tL.idL WHERE tL.Selection=1", sqliteCon);
    var RD = cmdRD.ExecuteScalar();

    var tot =pass;
    using (cmdRD)
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdRD.ExecuteReader())
         {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader[0].ToString()==fail)
                {
                            tot = fail;
                            break;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(tot);
        }
    }
```

i'm arrived to that(1.1) it works but i've to insert the TOT into RProva

Comment: Does your query return one row or multiple rows?

Comment: the first?the first query can return 1 or multiple rows based on if the user have selected 1 or more rows

Comment: Check the [DataAdapter.Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netframework-4.7.2&term=DataAdapter.Fill) and the [IDataReader.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netframework-4.7.2&term=IDataReader.Read)

Comment: You will need to loop around the rows in `cmdRD` to see if you got a fail, if not, it's a pass.

Comment: ok i was arrived to that but i can't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comment I think you misunderstood ExecuteScalar:
ExecuteScalar executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar)

I dont know the Type of "RD" or "PASS", but the IF in your example (when using ExecuteScalar) seems OK. Else when you are using ExecuteReader you should use some kind of an loop to iterate through the Items. Like this:

```
string pass = "abc"; // guessing types and values
string fail = "failed";
string sqliteCon = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=BooksDb";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqliteCon))
{
    connection.Open();

    var queryString = @"SELECT ResItem AS RD 
                FROM tSE 
                JOIN tL ON tSE.idSE = tL.idL 
                WHERE tL.Selection=1";

    var values = new List<string>();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                values.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    var queryInsert = @"INSERT INTO tSD (NomeItem,ResItemDet,DateStartDet,DateEndDet) 
                                VALUES (@NI, @RProva, @DATESE, @DATEED)";
    using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(queryInsert, connection))
    {
        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            command2.Parameters.Clear();
            if (value.Equals(pass))
            {
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", value);
            }
            else
            {
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", fail);
            }
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Theres for sure a better way, but maybe this helps you out.

EDIT:
Here is how I would implement your code example:

```
using (SqlConnection sqliteCon = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    sqliteCon.Open();
    var values = new List<string>();
    var query = "SELECT ResItem AS RD FROM tSE JOIN tL ON tSE.idSE=tL.idL WHERE tL.Selection=1";
    using (SqlCommand cmdRD = new SqlCommand(query, sqliteCon))
    {
        var RD = cmdRD.ExecuteScalar();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdRD.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                values.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    int generatedId = 0;
    var query2 = "INSERT INTO tSD(NomeItem,ResItemDet,DateStartDet,DateEndDet) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES (@NI,@RProva,@DATESE,@DATEED)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query2, sqliteCon))
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESE", DATESE);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", DATEED);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NI", NI);

            if (value.Equals(pass))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RProva", fail);
            }
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        generatedId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    var query3 = "UPDATE tSE SET FK_TSD_id = @tsdId FROM tL JOIN tSE ON tL.idL = tSE.idSE WHERE tL.Selection=1 ";
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query3, sqliteCon))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsdId", generatedId);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u, i know yet that ExecuteSaclar can return only the first position, i know that the perfect one is executeReader but i've got others queryes(executeNonQuery)that doesn't allow to me to use a executeReader

Comment: I added an example from your updated code. I just checked the syntax not the actual results. And you probably have to change the SqlConnection to a Sqlite one.

Comment: i really appreciate all your work but i can't modify that code, it's too sensible... watch at the point 1.1 i think that i'm near,i've based that on your code... but it tells me the that i've to declare @RProva as scalar